# Java adding items to a collection

Tags: java

I need to create a method call loadBooks. When called, this method create 5 books and adds them to the collection.

What i Have

```
public class Library
{

private ArrayList<Book> library;


public Library()
{
   library = new ArrayList<>();
}

 public void loadBooks()
  {
   library.add(new Book("T")); 
   library.add(new Book("A"));
   library.add(new Book("C"))
   library.add(new Book("O"));
   library.add(new Book("S"));
   }
```

Book Class:

```
class Book
 {

private String author;
private String title;
private int numberOfPages;          
private String refNumber;           
private int borrowed;
private int total;
private boolean courseText;


public Book(String bookAuthor, String bookTitle, int numPages,boolean isCourseText)
{
    author = bookAuthor;
    title = bookTitle;
    numberOfPages = numPages;
    refNumber = "";
    courseText = isCourseText;   
}
```

I get a constructor Book in class Book cannot be applied to given types error then if i change it to something else it says cannot find class error.
Any ideas what to do or fix my code?

Comment: At first glance, I don't see anything wrong with your code or design.  It sounds like maybe the `Book` class isn't on your classpath when you build.

Comment: And what constructors does `Book` have?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] that generates this problem. As it stands, we can only guess wildly at the cause of your problem.

Comment: So I should post my whole codes for both of my classes?

Comment: I think we'll need your Book class, but have a look at the link posted by @KenY-N

Comment: Yes. That would be ideal.

Comment: I add Book class with fields and constructor

Comment: Another <sigh> - your constructor has 4 parameters yet you call it with only one.

Comment: Was about to post that i re-read the error and saw that i forgot to add the other three. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're book class constructor accsepts 4 perameters, yet you're only passing it one in your `loadBooks()` method.

Just change your lines in `loadBooks()` to something like:

```
library.add(new Book("Author", "T", 1205 , true));
```

Comment: Was about to post that i re-read the error and saw that i forgot to add the other three. thanks.